# Error when using pyrealsense2 with multithreading

Tags: python, multithreading, numpy, realsense, nvidia-jetson-nano

I'm trying to write a program in Python, where the main thread will read depth frames from a RealSense camera and put them in a queue,
and another thread that will run inference on them with a YoloV5 TensorRT model. The program runs on a Jetson Nano.

For some reason, after reading about 15 frames the program crashes with the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test2.py", line 59, in <module>
    img = np.asanyarray(c.colorize(DEPTH).get_data())
RuntimeError: Error occured during execution of the processing block! See the log for more info
```

Here is the full code:

```
from queue import Queue
import numpy as np 
from ObjectDetection.objectDetectionV2 import ODModel, letterbox
import torch
import time
from threading import Thread
import cv2
from Camera.Realsense import RealSense  # custom class for reading from Realsense camera

def detect(queue):
    while True:
        if not queue.empty():
            img0 = queue.get()
            if img0 is None: break
            img = letterbox(img0, 416, stride=32, auto=False)[0] # YoloV5 preprocessing
            img = img.transpose((2, 0, 1))[::-1]  # HWC to CHW, BGR to RGB
            img = np.ascontiguousarray(img)
            
            print("loading image...")
            img = torch.tensor(img)
            print("loaded image")
            img = img.float()  # uint8 to fp16/32
            img /= 255  # 0 - 255 to 0.0 - 1.0
            result = model(img)
            print(result)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    queue = Queue()
    print("loading model")
    model = ODModel()
    print("model loaded")
    rs = RealSense()
    p = Thread(target=detect, args=(queue,)) 
    c = rs.colorizer
    p.start()
    for i in range(100):
         RGB, DEPTH = rs.getData() 
         img = np.asanyarray(c.colorize(DEPTH).get_data())
         queue.put(img)
    queue.put(None)
    p.join()
    model.destroy()
    print("Exiting Main Thread")
```

I tried commenting everything out and checking line by line, and I think the error is because of the `c.colorizer` taking too much time? When I deleted it the error went away (but of course the inference failed).

If I don't remove it then the error appears after the line `img = np.ascontiguousarray(img)`. But then why is the error not on this line?

If I limit the size of the queue to at most 14, the problem stops, but then the queue is blocking so everything slows down. Also the error mentions a log, but I have no idea where it is.

Can anyone help me understand what I did wrong? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

this line reserves memory, and limiting the queue size also limits memory usage so you most likely ran out of memory.

a possible solution is to just limit the queue size to 1 sample, you always get the most recent result that is within the timeframe of your processing time.

another solution is to use a [deque](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque) of say, 5 elements, your producer will append, and your consumer will pop to get the most recent item, and if the deque length is greater than 3 elements then your producer will `popleft` to keep the deque bounded, and the "counting" should be in the worker thread instead of the main thread, while the main thread will have an infinite loop to guarantee 100 images were processed before breaking out of the infinite loop. (simply switching role with the worker thread.)